# Create Table Product Ecommerce Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, e-commerce, export-to-csv

Please help me the process of making Web Ecommerce, is there any example of Product Table like Bhinneka[dot]com?

I have created the required field example.
But still confused in the Product Image Field and Product Specification.

1. Product Image: I created 1 image field for the product's large thumbnail and the product gallery field (which contained some product images). -> [Product Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBTb1.jpg)
2. Product Specifications: This is the attribute / specification,
   example in woocommerce product data either in the field of each or
   in a field. -> [Attribute/Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbRlT.jpg)

Here's an example of the Product table field, which I created: goo[dot]gl/ngYsy3 please correct it or some suggestions
I want to create a CSV, so upload the product with CSV.

Comment: Hire testers!!!!

Comment: can you provide your current db structure so that i can check and suggest if any improvement required or not.

Comment: This complete Database ->goo[dot]gl/47WpVH, but still not finished. Because I want to put the product table first

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below configuration schema.In this **status** field will help you to `enable/disable` specific size and color.

```
Product Table

product_id | int
name       | varchar
description| text
category   | cat_id

Product Picture
id         | INT
product_id | INT
picture    | INT
is_default | INT 
status     | TINYINT

Product_color_map

id         | INT
product_id | INT
color_id   | INT
status     | TINYINT

Product_size_map

id         | INT
product_id | INT
size_id    | INT
status     | TINYINT

Color Table

color_id   | int
color      | varchar  

Category Table

cat_id     | int
category   | varchar
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm still designing the database, and I've got it. Here are the results I designed, please review -> goo[dot]gl/uMaSuD

Sorry i did not duplicate your post, but i think use your way

Comment: Your database schema looks good but I suggest you to separate your description and seo related in another table, so your product table will not be too much heavy and help you to get faster data.

Comment: Ok thanks for review :) Very helpful, if I have trouble going back :)

Comment: Sure, @RanggaSetiaga, Glad to help you.